# How could I override configuration value in Apache Flink?

Tags: monitoring, apache-flink, prometheus

I'm trying to gather metrics from Apache Flink into Prometheus. Flink documentation says that I need to add following lines to my flink-conf.yaml:

```
metrics.reporter.promgateway.class: org.apache.flink.metrics.prometheus.PrometheusPushGatewayReporter
metrics.reporter.promgateway.host: localhost
metrics.reporter.promgateway.port: 9091
metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName: myJob
```

I want to mark different jobs with different names inside of Prometheus. How could I override configuration parameter *metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName* on per-job basis (each job is running inside of its own Flink cluster session)?

There is a couple of problems:

- I can't override flink-conf.yaml. I've found only FLINK_CONF_DIR parameter to override whole configuration directory. But it doesn't look like a right solution to override configuration directory for every single job.
- I can't override initial configuration of StreamExecutionEnvironment because it is being constructed inside of *StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment* method and can't be modified after environment's initialization.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify the effective configuration by specifying a dynamic property when starting a Flink job cluster. Assuming that you are deploying to Yarn the command would look like:

```
bin/flink run -m yarn-cluster -yD metrics.reporter.promgateway.jobName=myCustomJob <USER_CODE_JAR>
```

The dynamic properties are sent to the Yarn cluster and overwrite existing configuration key value pairs.

Comment: what happens if you want to load new value of the property after starting the job? Is this possible at all?

Comment: This is not possible. The configuration will only be read once at cluster start up.

Comment: What if I'm not deploying with Yarn? I just use High Availability mode?

Comment: Then you should configure the `flink-conf.yml` with the respective configuration options.