# Custom configuration file flink-conf.yaml

Tags: apache-flink

I need to specify different Flink settings for different applications. In other words, each application should run with its custom file `flink-conf.yaml`. What is the proper way to do it?

I found some old recommendations to declare `FLINK_CONF_DIR` pointing to a custom directory with Flink configuration files (for example: [How could I override configuration value in Apache Flink?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53376812)). However, the official Flink documentation does not mention the `FLINK_CONF_DIR` variable at all (as of Flink 1.13). Therefore I have doubts, that this way is officially recommended and supported by Flink developers.

**UPDATE 1: Details on application running**

I am running Flink on YARN in the [Application mode](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/deployment/resource-providers/yarn.html#application-mode). Here is how I launch the application:

```
"$flink_home/bin/flink" \
  run-application \
  --target yarn-application \
  --class com.example.App1
```

The out-of-the-box Flink configuration is located in the `$flink_home/conf` directory. As I have several applications App1, App2, ..., I want them to use their respective Flink configurations instead of the out-of-the-box configuration.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. The docs are being updated; see https://github.com/apache/flink/pull/15845.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR: The paragraph about `FLINK_CONF_DIR` was accidentally removed when the Flink on YARN docs were rewritten for the Flink 1.12 release. It is still the intended and supported way to establish per-application settings in YARN clusters.

---

Other ways to override the configuration:

You can override the settings specified in the cluster's `flink-conf.yaml` file with settings you specify on the command line, as described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53396526/20008230).

You can also override specific settings from the global configuration in your code, e.g.:

```java
Configuration conf = new Configuration();
conf.setString("state.backend", "filesystem");
env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment(conf);
```

You can also load all of the settings in a `flink-conf.yaml` file from your application code, via

```java
FileSystem.initialize(GlobalConfiguration.loadConfiguration("/path/to/conf/directory"));
```

And with Kubernetes you can mount different ConfigMaps for different applications.

Comment: I am using Application Mode (updated the post with more details). Are you suggesting to make a separate copy of the Flink distribution directory for each application?

Comment: I was imagining kubernetes when I said that, not yarn.

Comment: As far as I can tell from a quick survey of the code, FLINK_CONF_DIR should still work with yarn.

Comment: With Kubernetes, one can mount different ConfigMaps under `$flink_home/conf` for different applications - that's clear.

Comment: I also glanced through the source code and guessed that `FLINK_CONF_DIR` should work. Nevertheless, I'm worrying that this way is undocumented. Maybe it's a dirty hack that will be removed in a future Flink version. It would be good to get an answer from a Flink maintainer.

Comment: I checked with the developer who rewrote those docs and learned that the mention of FLINK_CONF_DIR was accidentally removed. He will restore it.